# % of API Calls in v2.x stuck

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

We updated the `facebook sdk` on `Android` as well as `Django` Backend(using [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/docs/index.rst)) to latest almost a month back. Facebook still complains that `19% of api calls` are still made from `V1 graph api`. Only reason I could think of is from users who have not updated the app. But this figure is stuck on `exactly 81%` from past 2 weeks. Is there anything that I am missisng. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did u find an answer to this?

Comment: No, didn't find any answers. Please upvote the question to promote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine as long as you have updated your application to use the latest Android (maybe iOS) Facebook SDK's and released the new versions in the App Store and Google Play. That last 19% is due to users not having updated to the latest version of your application. Also, that information is an average, so you should see it increase (perhaps slowly) over time.

If you're confident that your app was migrated correctly, you can force your calls to v2.x from the migrations tab of your Facebook app settings: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/settings/migrations/